# How to return parent with children (entire family) using self-referential relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a customer model in Laravel.  Field as an example:

- id: integer
- first: string
- last: string
- parent_id: integer

I can get the parent and the children using the following methods:

```
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'parent_id','id');
    }
```

Is there a way to add a family method that returns both the parent (if there is one) and the members (if there are any)?  I tried:

```
public function family()
    {
        return $this->with('members');
    }
```

But it doesn't return a relationship instance, so it didn't work.  Any ideas?  I can work around it in the controller by doing:
       `$family = !$customer->parent_id ? $customer->members->push($customer) : $customer->parent->members->push($customer->parent);`

Comment: As a relationship method, not really, but you could define an accessor that combines `parent` and `members`, something like `public function getFamilyAttribute(){ return $this->members->merge(collect($this->parent)); }`, then `$customer->family` would return a single Collection containing `members` and `parent` (although, there wouldn't be any indication of who is what)

Comment: Thanks!  I don't need to know who is what, but if I did it would be the record with the parent_id field not null.

Comment: in the model you cant use this method because you just must return a relationship instance and the family method is not a relation but you can use with like this: `Custmer::->with('answeres', 'questions')->first()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim Lewis' comment, in case anyone else searches for a solution, here is what worked well.  First of all, the parent_id field will indicate whether or not they are head of household.  If it's null, they are the parent.  I modified my model class to add the following:

```
public function getFamilyAttribute()
    {
        return !$this->parent_id ? $this->members->prepend($this) : $this->parent->members->prepend($this->parent);
    }
```

Now instead of putting logic all over the place, I can just call customer->family and all the members are displayed with the parent as the first member.

Why is this important?  Because in my application, I need to know how many customers had a visit in the last billing period.  I also need to know how much was paid (sometimes other members pay the bill in a month) for the entire family.  I can now use other methods and call them just as simply.

Example:

```
public function getFamilyApptsAttribute() {
        return Appt::select(['id','customer_id','appt_date','appt_time','appt_note')->with('patient')->whereIn('customer_id',$this->family->pluck('id')->toArray())->orderByDesc('id')->get();
    }
```